# How can I get a rotated stick in Minecraft: bedrock edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have minecraft bedrock edition 1.12.0. I have seen a video where you can make a pickaxe called "Not even a wooden pickaxe". It was weak, but I want it to make a rainbow pickaxe. Can I craft this or is it a behavior pack?

Answer (score 2):

Not in vanilla. You’ll need to install a data pack to do it, which is exclusive to Java or PC edition. Right now, for the Pocket Edition of the game, behavior packs are very limited and they only allow for replacement of mobs or blocks that are currently in the game, for example replacing a chicken with a duck. Custom crafting recipes and changes to loot tables etc. are exclusive to Java Edition.

Comment: This is incorrect. Behaviour packs now allow custom mobs, tools, and items, not just replacing existing mobs. You still cant make custom blocks, however, outside of education edition.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the texture and names of the pickaxe, you'll have to use a resource pack add-on. A useful website here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Creating_resource_pack_add-ons.
Additionally you'll want to create a  `texts` folder and in that folder create a file called `en_US.lang` which you will write `item.(diamond|golden|stone|iron|wooden)_pickaxe.name=Rainbow Pickaxe`. It's rather complicated.